# How do I concatenate a space to a string after joining them together?

Tags: python, string, join, concatenation, sorting

```
firstString = raw_input("Please enter a String ")



print "This is the sorted ordered " + "".join(sorted(firstString))




secondString = raw_input("please enter a second String ")


print ''.join(sorted(secondString))

thirdString = raw_input("Please enter a third String ")

print ''.join(sorted(thirdString))

fourthString = raw_input("Please enter a fourth String ")

print ''.join(sorted(fourthString))
```

I input "Hello World my name is John" and I get "HJWadeehilllmmnnooorsy"

How do I get a result like this "Hello Wdlor my aemn is Jhno"

I get the result I want if it's just one word, but if it's a sentence it's going to just get all mushed together, how do I add a space and have the letters get sorted out on their own?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split()` string function to get a list of space-separated words.

```
firstString = raw_input("Please enter a String ")
for word in firstString.split():
    print ''.join(sorted(word))
    print ' '
```

Comment: How can I get the words in a single string?

Comment: Very similar to @zondo's answer below: `newString = " ".join(''.join(sorted(word)) for word in firstString.split())`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
print "This is the sorted ordered " + " ".join("".join(sorted(word)) for word in firstString.split())
```

Comment: You've got one too many `)`'s there, plus you need another `join` on the individual letters of each word.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Thank you for pointing that out.  I have edited my answer.